# Problems when operating on Map<Class<?>, Object> in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, raw-types, enumset

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private Map<Class<?>, Object> member;

    public <E> void putEnumSet(Class<E> enumSetType, E enumSet) {
        this.member.put(enumSetType, enumSetType.cast(enumSet));
    }

    public <E> E getEnumSet(Class<E> enumType) {
        return enumType.cast(this.member.get(enumType));
    }

};

public enum Category {
    // ...
};
```

The `member` in `MyClass` is used to store several kinds of **EnumSet** with different **Enum type**. While implementing relative methods, I meet some problems: when I try to call the method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EnumSet<Category> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Category.class);

    MyClass<Word> newClass = new MyClass<Word>();
    newClass.putEnumSet(set.getClass(), set);

}
```

Here comes the error:

> The method `putEnumSet(Class<E>, E)` in the type `MyClass<Word>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<capture#1-of ? extends EnumSet>, EnumSet<Category>)`

How to deal with this problem? I think it may come from **raw type** or **type erasure**, but I do not know the main reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deal with this problem?

```
E extends EnumSet<E>
```

This is very confusing as it says you have to have a element `E` which must extend `EnumSet<E>` i.e. you need an element type which is itself an `EnumSet` of `E`

---

You have a problem that all EnumSet classes are the same at runtime.  I.e. there is only one EnumSet.class.  You are better off recording the class of elements.

```
public class MyClass {

    private Map<Class, Set> member;

    public <E> void putEnumSet(Class<E> elementType, Set<E> enumSet) {
        this.member.put(elementType, enumSet);
    }

    public <E> Set<E> getEnumSet(Class<E> elementType) {
        return (Set<E>) this.member.get(elementType));
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, that's right, after **type erasure**, all EnumSets are of the same type, EnumSet.class. Using element type as a key is exactly a good idea. While, would you please explain the error `(Class<capture#1-of ? extends EnumSet>, EnumSet<Category>)`, since I am still confused about it?

Comment: @stanleyerror the confusing part is that your `E` type must extends an EnumSet<E> i.e. you have a recursive definition.

Comment: Finally the `Map<Class<?>, Object> member` is like: `[String.class -> Set<String>, Integer.class -> Set<Integer>, ..., Enum1.class -> EnumSet<Enum1>, Enum2.class -> EnumSet<Enum2>, ...]`. Is there a way to judge whether a `key` of `member` is a Enum's class? Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: @stanleyerror all `enum` extend the class Enum , if that is what you mean.

Comment: The Enum<E> is direct subclass of Object, not the subclass of Class<T>. If the Enum1.class returns Enum<Enum1>, it is not a valid key of the map, how can it added to the member? And in your answer, the type of key is Class rather than Class<?>, what is the difference between these classes? I got confused with all these stuff, would it necessary to push these as a new question.

Comment: @stanleyerror you have a number of unrelated questions.  To test whether a key is a member of an `enum` you can check `if (key instanceof Enum)`   Instance of `Enum1` can be assigned to an `Enum<Enum1>`.  The class as it's instances have different types.  `Class<?>` is an unknown class which will only allow operations where the type is not used. `Class` will allow any operation.

Answer (score 1):

`Class` objects can be difficult to use. As you have noticed, they're not easy to use with generic types because due to type erasure `EnumSet<Category>.class` is not legal code. It would be impossible to use your approach to store `EnumSet`s for different `Enum`s because there is only one `Class` object for *all* `EnumSet`s, namely `EnumSet.class`.

One solution I have found to this is to replace `Class<?>` with my own key object. Here is a complete program demonstrating this approach.

```
public class Main {

    public enum Shape { SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE }

    // Here you would instantiate all the keys you will need.
    public static final ClassKey<String> STRING_KEY = new ClassKey<String>();
    public static final ClassKey<EnumSet<Shape>> SHAPE_SET_KEY = new ClassKey<EnumSet<Shape>>();

    public static final class ClassKey<T> { private ClassKey() {} }

    private Map<ClassKey<?>, Object> member = new HashMap<ClassKey<?>, Object>();

    public <E extends Enum<E>> void putEnumSet(ClassKey<EnumSet<E>> enumSetType, EnumSet<E> enumSet) {
        this.member.put(enumSetType, enumSet);
    }

    public <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> getEnumSet(ClassKey<EnumSet<E>> enumType) {
        return (EnumSet<E>) member.get(enumType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        EnumSet<Shape> enumSet = EnumSet.allOf(Shape.class);
        main.putEnumSet(SHAPE_SET_KEY, enumSet);
        EnumSet<Shape> shapes = main.getEnumSet(SHAPE_SET_KEY);
        System.out.println(shapes);
    }
}
```

One major drawback to this approach is that you have to have a fixed bank of `ClassKey` objects. It would not work to create these objects on the fly because if you used`new ClassKey<EnumSet<Shape>>` to put an `EnumSet` into `member` and then tried to use `new ClassKey<EnumSet<Shape>>` to retrieve the `EnumSet`, you would find it would't work because the keys would not be equal. There is no way to write an `equals()` method for `ClassKey` that works because, due to type erasure, it would be impossible to tell a `ClassKey<EnumSet<Shape>>` from a `ClassKey<EnumSet<Category>>`.